# Getting an array from $.post()

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, debugging, jquery

I am using:

```
$.post('fromDB.php', function(data) {
    eval(data);
    console.log(data);
    updateTimer();
});
```

to get some arrays from php.
What php returns:

```
var todayTimeMinutes = [0, 45, 35, 25, 40, 0, 50, 40, 40, 30, 20];
var todayTimeHours = [0, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var todaySectionName = ["Before School", "Period 1", "Period 2", "Formtime", "Interval", "Period 3", "Period 4", "Lunchtime", "Period 5", "Period 6", "After School"];
console.log("Excecution time: 0.00058889389038086 seconds");
```

The console.log works fine. When I try to access values from the array inside the success function, it works fine. However, accessing it from updateTimer() does not work, and gives me this message in the chrome debugger:[image]

Comment: what does `updateTimer()` do? i guess you got error there

Comment: Lots. One thing it does is use todayTimeMinutes & todayTimeHours to work out the current todaySectionName

Comment: Is `updateTimer()` called outside of the success function?  If so, are those variables defined in the success function namespace or when `updateTimer()` can get to them?

Comment: The line (107) which seems to be causing the problem is this: for (i=0; i <= todaySectionName.length - 2; i++) {

Comment: @tandu at the end of updateTimer() is setTimeout("updateTimer()", 1000);

Comment: does updateTimer have access to those variables?  Are they defined globally?

Comment: If they are defined outside of a lower closure, they can be used outside that closure.  Like `var x = 1; function x() { alert(x); } x();` will alert '1', but `function x() { var x = 1; } x(); alert(x);` will not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are attempting to access todaySectionName within updateTimer(). In that case, the reason you're getting the error is that todaySectionName is not in scope in updateTimer.

So you either need to define updateTimer as a closure within your success function, or you need to find a different way to pass those values to updateTimer. (Like as arguments.)

So wherever updateTimer is defined, change its signature to this:

```
function updateTimer(todayTimeMinutes, todayTimeHours, todaySectionName) {
    // leave this the same
}
```

Then change your success function to this:

```
$.post('fromDB.php', function(data) {
    eval(data);
    console.log(data);
    updateTimer(todayTimeMinutes, todayTimeHours, todaySectionName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! This page shows the words "Thank you" in 465 languages. http://users.elite.net/runner/jennifers/thankyou.htm That's how many times I needed this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm gonna upvote this just because @JJ56 likes the answer so much.